# how should I send the output from a system commands executed on server to client in continuous fashion

Tags: java, servlets, processbuilder

I'm executing a system command on server which gives continuous output till it gets completed. Since it takes a long time to get completed, I want to sent the output from this system command to client in continuous fashion. Any suggestions on how should I do it.

Here is my snippet of code which executes the system command and has the input stream to read from.
I'm invoking this code form my servlet doPost.

```
  Process process = pb.start();
  final InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
  final StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer();


        Thread inputStreamThread = new Thread(){

            public void run() {



                String line;

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                try {

                    while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                            strBuff.append(line + "\n");

                    }       

                } catch (IOException e) {

                     logger.error("IO Exception occured in inputStreamThread=> "+e);

                }

            }

        };



        inputStreamThread.start();





        inputStreamThread.join();                        

        int exitVal = process.waitFor();
```

Comment: Simply write in the HTTP response stream and flush the data. or make an AJAX call from the client side after few seconds to fetch the next item from the server and send a token to identify the completion of the process to stop the client side thread/timer.

Comment: Braj I'm executing a system command on the server side and that gives a continuous output over a period of time. My target is not to wait for the system command to complete and send continuous pieces of output I'm getting from system command to client side browser. Now here is snippet from my system command executor utility which executes the system command and has the input stream to read from. Can you provide some help on how should I send this output in pieces to servlet which can send it back to client.